# Qlikview Ranking Expression

Tags: ranking, qlikview

Quick question,does anybody know how to set an expression in Qlikview whereby the user could rank as follows:

"Company X first always, followed by all other companies ranked by highest value to lowest value"

Apologies this might seem like a very basic question as I am a novice in Qlikview.

Thank you for your help,
Liam

Answer (score 2):

Set the sorting of the `company` field to be something like this:

```
if( company = 'Company6', 1000000, sum(value) )
```

Having the following data:

```
Companies:
Load * Inline [
  company, value
  Company1, 10
  Company5, 60
  Company2, 50
  Company3, 30
  Company4, 40
  Company6, 20  
];
```

And the result is below

[image]